# Array e tratamento de erros em jogo de números

Tags: java, array

O jogo é de descobrir números do adversário, mas não tipo loteria, tem que usar raciocínio para chegar até o número correto.

A regra é jogar com 4 números por vez sem repetir na mesma linha.
Sobre o array tenho as seguintes dúvidas.

1ª Posso digitar 4 números direto e armazenar direto em um array sem especificar indice por indice, direto por tamanho limite?

ex: `pal[i] = entrada.nextInt()`

Em vez do indice [i], guardar direto os 4 números, para deixar o for só para fazer a comparação

2º Caso não dê para fazer isso, como limitar apenas 1 número digitado por vez?

3ª No tratamentos de erros, no caso de digitar letra, que apenas avise que não pode e retorne a pedir o número, eu fiz mas ele aparece as duas mensagens após inserir letras, em vez de dar o aviso e só pedir para digitar 4 números.

Eu gostaria de dicas de forma mais manual, porque estou no começo explorando loop for e array, sei que tem bibliotecas para facilitar mas ainda não cheguei lá, e a ídeia do jogo é explorar onde começo a ter dificuldades, no caso preciso da direção apenas.

Esse jogo é feito no caderno, vou deixar um exemplo, mas no caderno o adversário as vezes passa os valores errados.
No campo "Você", apenas escolhe o número e abaixo é o adversário tentando encontrar, dai retornaria como no exemplo, e no lado direito é o próprio jogador tentando adivinhar o outro jogador

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class JogoNumeros {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer[] num = {1,2,3,4}; //Variável do jogador principal
        int[] pal =  new int[4]; //Variável do palpite do advesário
        List<Integer> n = Arrays.asList(num);
        int fim = 0;

        while(fim < 5){
            int bom = 0;
            int regular = 0; 
            int nenhum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < pal.length; i++){
                System.out.print("Digite 4 números: ");
                try{
                pal[i] = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    System.out.println("Digite apenas números"); //Após digitar letra fica aparecendo no console "Digite 4 números: " e "Digite apenas números"
                    pal[i] = entrada.nextInt();
                }

                nenhum = pal[i]; 
            }
             if( !n.contains(nenhum)){ //primeira comparação, caso não acerte nenhum
                System.out.println("Nenhum!!!!");
                }  

            for (int y = 0; y < pal.length; y++){
                if (pal[y] == num[y]){ //Caso exista o número e esteja na posição correta
                    bom += 1;
                }

                if ( n.contains(pal[y]) && pal[y]!= num[y]){
                    regular += 1; //Caso exista o número e não esteja na posição correta
                }
            }
                if(bom == 4){ //Acertando os 4 encerra o loop while
                    fim = bom;
                    System.out.println("Acertou");
                    break;
                }
            System.out.println(bom + " B e " + regular + " R");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trata tudo como string, simples ;)

Comment: @Articuno, como iniciante ainda não é tão simples para mim.
Acho que mesmo transformando em String, acabaria com as mesmas dificuldades em limitar caracter para somente número, e um número por vez, e também algo que não sei se é possível, digitar os 4 números e jogar tudo direto como se fosse indice+1, primeiro cai no 0, segundo no 1 e assim por diante.